# Editing multiple labels with single code block

Tags: vb.net

I want to edit a label's text. I have a chain of labels named  e1 , e2 , e3 , e4 ,e5 and so on.  I want to edit all of them with a single chunk of code, like this:

```
if ta.text = "whatever" then 
e(i).text = ta.text 
endif
```

In this case "i" is the variable which i will use to select which label will be edited. 
here is a sample of the code :

```
Form2.E(i).Text = em.Text
Form2.P(i).Text = p.Text
Form2.NS(i).Title = t.Text
```

This code isn't working can someone help me ?

Comment: One way to do this is to use `FindControl` and pass the id of the control you want to edit.  Is this WinForms, ASP.NET, MVC, WPF?

Comment: Are the labels that you mentioned here contained in some grid kind of control?

Comment: yes they are contained in a groupbox

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
if ta.text = "whatever" then 
  DirectCast(Me.FindControl("e" & i), Label).Text = ta.text
endif
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but unfortunately the code is not working

Answer (score 0):

How about this ...

```
If ta.text = "whatever" Then 

    CType(Me.Controls("e" & format(i)), Label).Text = ta.text

End If
```

Comment: i appreciate your reply and i am very grateful . but unfortunately it gives a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error

Comment: yea i got the problem .. sorry for the irritation . the problem is that it's contained in a groupbox

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myLabel As Label = CType(Me.Controls("e" & i), Label)
myLabel.Text = ...whatever value you want to put here
```

Comment: worked but the problem is that the object is contained in a groupbox

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `i` is an integer, and the controls aren't inside another control, this code will work:

```
    If ta.Text = "whatever" Then
        Me.Controls("e" + i.ToString).Text = ta.Text
    End If
```

If the controls are inside another control, you have to qualify them with the name of the control instead of `Me`.

Comment: this wouldn't work as u mentioned because the object is contained in a groupbox

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to do these sort of things is to make a specialized version of the control.

Quick example of a specialized `LinkedLabel` control:

```
Public Class LinkedLabel
    Inherits Label

    Private _nextLabel As Label

    Public Sub New(nextLabel As Label)
        _nextLabel = nextLabel
    End Sub

    ' Default constructor is still needed for the designer view.
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
        Debug.Print(Text)
        If _nextLabel IsNot Nothing Then
            _nextLabel.Text = "whatever you want"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

When you change the text on a `LinkedLabel` instance, it will also change the text on `_nextLabel` (if set). `nextLabel` can be either a standard label, or another `LinkedLabel`, which in turn can have another linked label. And so on.